# Add column to dataframe but some columns disapper - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I read a large csv file into dataframe **df**, which has 240760 rows × 33 columns.

However, after I add a column to df as the following:

```
df['a'] = processed_data
```

I notice that one original column disappers and the column number remains 33. Is there any size limitation for dataframe?

Comment: How are you checking the content of variable df? If you are using print(df), it might not show you all the values contained in the variable 'df' due to the large number of values in df. Instead try checking number of columns with len() function or use a for loop and print the contents of df variable

Comment: I didn't print(df), but try to print the specific column like print(df['b']) and it shows error

Comment: Maybe original `df` contains column `a` and then it is overwritten. Please check it by `print df.columns`

Comment: I am sure that I did not overwrite the column because their names are quite different. "a" here is just an example.

Comment: unless you post raw data and code that reproduces the problem then this becomes a guessing game

Comment: The raw data is too large and I cannot post it. But I find it is ok now to add more columns. Is it a connection problem of ipython notebook? I have encountered this problems several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem:
I did this

```
#Create a random DF with 33 columns
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,33),columns=np.arange(33))
df['33']=np.random.randn(2)
df.info()
Output: 34 columns
```

Thus, I'm sure your problem has nothing to do with the limit on the number of columns. Perhaps your column is being overwritten somewhere. 
Make sure you don't use inplace=True for any commands.

**Update:** Certain methods, for example, if you ever resampled your data during processing, it could drop columns from your dataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

The following works on my machine:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))

processed_data = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
df['new'] = processed_data

print df
```

returns

```
                A         B         C         D    new
2013-01-01 -0.670405 -0.526197  0.373418 -0.181366  0
2013-01-02 -0.451113  1.265380 -0.240582  0.435271  0
2013-01-03  0.804812  0.143988  1.535558  0.640288  0
2013-01-04  0.996395  0.401765  0.288209  0.099472  0
2013-01-05 -0.391577 -0.929378 -0.877802  1.549503  0
2013-01-06 -0.222499  0.713709  0.666735  1.954450  0
```

- Maybe, column 'a' already existed and you have simply assigend new data to it (rather than creating a new column entry)?
- also try **print df.info()**, which gives you a printout of the df information, such as number of columns and object types.
- try **print df.head()**, which prints the first five rows of the DataFrame. Maby easier to check what you're looking at.
- try exporing your DataFrame as csv and have a look at it with a text editor or Excel: [pd.to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)